# A scholarship organization is publishing my personal information on their website

Tags: europe, privacy

In February 2018, I received a one-time scholarship (1000 €) from a private association in the EU. A few months ago, I noticed the organization published on their website private information of the scholarship recipients: name, town and photography of each person.

This is a problem for me, because this appears on the first page of results when I search my name on Google. This means, everyone who looks up my name on Google will be able to know where I live. This is even more a problem, because I live in a small town, so it is very easy to deduce my house address.

I had emailed the association, and I was told they were "not even sure they could technically remove the information" because "this is the first time we received such a request" and "no scholarship recipient ever had a problem with this".

This was a few months ago, and my personal information is still published on their website.

I would still prefer to have this information removed. How should I politely approach this situation?

Comment: Sorry for your problem but this is a legal/social problem not an academic one, so off-topic here.

Comment: Where should I post then?

Comment: I'm not sure, but for legal issues there is https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: They are required by law to remove the information when you request it.

Comment: Some scholarships applications require you to give permission to disseminate your information on their website, etc. Are you sure this particular scholarship did not have something like this in the fine print? In any case, you should think carefully about whether you really want to fight this. Making such requests after being given a scholarship might be seen as ungracious by some